# Sum up all the qty from a column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have column `qty` in my table, and I want to sum up all the `qty` from this column in a variable:

```
$get_sold = "select qty from pending_orders where product_id='$p_id' AND order_status=='done'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $get_sold);
```

Comment: how can i get my sum up value from $result variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need sum to your column in your query by using `sum(qty)as totals` and also remove `==` from `order_status` it is `=`

you need to use `mysqli_fetch_row` to get your sum data into your variable

```
<?php
$get_sold = "select sum(`qty`)as totals from `pending_orders` where `product_id`='".$p_id."' AND `order_status`='done'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$get_sold);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$row[0];// get your total sum
```

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
$get_sold = "select sum(`qty`) as sum from pending_orders where product_id='$p_id' AND order_status='done'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$get_sold);
```

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['sum'];

Comment: in where clause, you are comparing order_status with `==` should be `=`

Comment: how can i get my sum up value from $result variable ?

Answer (score 0):

try using, MySql `sum` function

```
$get_sold = "select sum(qty) total_qty from pending_orders where product_id='$p_id' AND order_status='done'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$get_sold);
```

Comment: why downvote ? make sure to specify reason in comments

Answer (score 0):

you should use 
select **sum(qty) as sumqty** from pending_orders where product_id='$p_id' AND order_status='done'

Also mention, that in mysql you need to write on equal sign instead of two

Comment: how can i get my sum up value from $result variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Most people have responded here with a quick copy/paste, but I feel like it would be better suited to format your query nicely for readability sake to help you identify the issue.

```
$get_sold = "
    SELECT SUM(`qty`) as `total_quantity`
    FROM `pending_orders`
    WHERE `product_id` = '$p_id' AND `order_status` = 'done'
";

$result = $con->query($get_sold);

if ( !$result ) {
    die("MySQL error: " . $con->error);
}

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$quantity = $row['total_quantity'];
```

Comment: how can i get my sum up value from $result variable ?

Answer (score -1):

CHANE QUERY , SUM(column_name) gives sum of all numbers in column_name

```
$get_sold = "select SUM(qty) as total from pending_orders where product_id='$p_id' AND order_status='done'";
```

Comment: in where clause, you are comparing order_status with `==` should be `=`

Comment: how can i get my sum up value from $result variable ?

Comment: it was mistake ,i just copied his query string,without  looking  his where clause

Comment: @Jawwad Rafiq your sum is collected in total ,use total to get  sum ,treat it as column name

Comment: @Jawwad Rafiq  check i have made changes

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp123\www\myshop3 - Copy\admin_area\view_products.php on line 75

Comment: var_dump($get_sold); and run o/p in mysql